# How do you add a variable prefix to ASP.Net Core API route?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, routes

I have a ASP.Net Core API web application.

The controller is defined like this:

```
[Route("/api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
 public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
 {
        // GET api/values
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }
}
```

I want to be able to call the API with a variable path which denotes the customer.  For example, I'd like to do something like this:

```
[Route("/[customername]/api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
        // GET api/values
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
        {
            // TODO: Somehow get the value of [customername]?

            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a route param:

```
[Route("{customername}/api/[controller]")]
```

Comment: and the action will need the parameter.

Comment: Not necessarily. Just because a route param exists doesn't mean your action must accept it. The OP may opt to utilize an action filter or override something like `OnActionExecuting` in the controller, for example, and manually access the param.